# Pandas replace characters within string based on regex match?

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I want to replace some characters within a string in pandas (based on a match to the entirety of the string), while leaving the rest of the string unchanged.

For instance, replace dashes with decimals in a number string IF the dash isn't at the start of the number string:

'26.15971'   -> '26.15971'

'1030899'    -> '1030899'

'26-404700'  -> '26.404700'

'-26-403268' -> '-26.403268'

Code:

```
# --- simple dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['26.15971','1030899','26-404700']})

# --- regex that only matches items of interest
regex_match = '^\d{1,2}-\d{1,8}'
df.col1.str.match(regex_match)

# --- not sure how to only replace the middle hypens?
# something like  df.col1.str.replace('^\d{1,2}(-)\d{1,8}','^\d{1,2}\.\d{1,8}') ??
# unclear how to get a repl that only alters a capture group and leaves the rest 
# of the string unchanged
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using a regex replacement with lookarounds:

```
df["col1"] = df["col1"].str.replace("(?<=\d)-(?=\d)", ".")
```

The regex pattern `(?<=\d)-(?=\d)` targets every dash sitting in between two numbers and replaces it with dot.

We could also approach this using capture groups:

```
df["col1"] = df["col1"].str.replace("(\d{2,3})-(\d{4,8})", "\\1.\\2")
```

Comment: Very nice!   So I think a positive lookbehind can't be variable width like `(?<=\d{2,3})` which reduces flexibility in the match.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @Mark_Anderson Actually, you _can_ use a variable width positive lookahead, so this would be legitimate also: `(?<=\d)-(?=\d{2,3})`

Comment: Agreed, but is there a way to get flexibility in the lookbehind?  I still really like the solution , but wondering if there is a way to get full flexibility (If lookbehind can't be flexible, maybe get 3 capture groups`(\d{2,3})(?P<hypen>-)(\d{4,8})` and only swap out the middle capture group that has the hypen?)

Comment: @Mark_Anderson I don't know why you think you need this, but I updated my answer anyway.  I think just asserting that even one digit be on either side of the dash should be OK logic here.

Comment: Just a general principle.  More flexibility is more good.  Mostly in case someone with a similar problem ends up on this post.